# How do I find out what the .fit function of a scipy stat distribution returns?

Tags: python, scipy

I tried running `.fit` on a `dweibull` distribution from `scipy.stats`

I get a list of three values but what are they?
looking here:
[Scipy Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.dweibull.html#scipy.stats.dweibull)

I can't see any description of what fit returns.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html

Comment: That tells me that beta has `a, b, loc, scale` but not other distributions? In `Returns` it says it returns `shape, loc, scale` but different distributions return different numbers of params. eg `norm` returns 2?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. You get as much values as there are parameters in your distribution. Since the 1d normal distribution only has location and scale parameters, you obviously will only get a tuple of two floats.

Comment: Oh the bigger problem is I am loop fitting other distributions and I get back some fits that have 4 params some with 2 etc then when I look up maths formulas for distributions it gives me `k` and `alpha` and `beta` and I dunno how they relate to my fit result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a tuple of `<shapes>, loc, scale`. dweibull has one shape parameter, so you get three items. `norm` does not have shape parameters, hence you only get two for loc and scale, etc

The idiom is that you can unpack the output of `fit` into a call to `pdf`, `cdf` et al:

```
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> data = stats.beta.rvs(a=1, b=2, size=100, random_state=101)
>>> xxx = stats.beta.fit(data)
>>> stats.beta.pdf(0.1, *xxx)
1.7748574630838663
>>> stats.beta.mean(*xxx)
0.33473342172664911
```